# Problem consuming JSON object in a servlet

Tags: jquery, json, servlets

This is what i'm trying to do and its pretty simple but i'm getting stuck: I'm trying to send a JSON object formed in JSP to a server side servlet and parse it .

What i've done till now:

- Constructed the json.
- sending the json to the backend

```
$.ajax({
            data: jsontosend,
            url: 'MYSERVLET?name=asdf',
            success: function(res){
                alert('posted');
            }
        })
```

Problem:

- What name is this JSON refrenced by so i can get it in the servlet using the request.getParameter() ?
- When i print request.getParameterNames() , i get the parameter name as the JSON string itself so the output of all parameter names inside the MYSERVLET looks like this

```
Parameter = name
Parameter = {"ticker":"asd","date":"asd","bucket":"300","entry":[{"type":"asd","indicator":"asd","condition":"asd"}],"exit":[{"type":"qwe","indicator":"qwe","condition":"qwe"}]}
```

Anyone have an idea as to what the problem is ?

Also i tried looking at this [question here on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5338943/read-json-string-in-servlet) but the same problem exists there too. Also there is a [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7164123/how-to-fetch-jquery-json-request-parameters-in-servlet) which hasn't been answered .

Help! :(

Comment: Have you used something like Firefox's LiveHeaders to see what's being sent? You'll be able to see all of the key-value pairs being sent to the referring servlet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Read http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#sending-data-to-server:

> The data option can contain either a query string of the form
>   key1=value1&key2=value2, or a map of the form {key1: 'value1', key2:
>   'value2'}. If the latter form is used, the data is converted into a
>   query string using jQuery.param() before it is sent.

So, you should use

```
$.ajax({
        data: {theNameOfTheParameter : jsontosend,
               name : 'asdf'},
        url: 'MYSERVLET',
        success: function(res){
            alert('posted');
        }
    })
```

and use `request.getParameter("theNameOfTheParameter")` to get the JSON string.

Answer (score 0):

You don't get the json object in your servlet. JQuery transforms it into http parameters like what you get from a form. Example: ?ticker=asd&bucket=300

So to answer your question. There is no single name. The json objected is exploded t multiple names.

EDIT: try adding 
    type: 'post'

for your request. You can also add 
    processData: false
 in which case JQuery will send json and not http params. Anyway I really recommend using a http debugger like fiddler which will make it apperant what is being sent back and forth.

Comment: I just tried it by doing `System.out.println(request.getParameter("ticker"));` and i get **null** :(

Comment: @shreyas: did u find the solution ?? plz share if u did.